# How to correctly interface an existing sealed class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

After having my code being reviewed on CodeReview, I am stuck on the question how to make my piece of code more abstract.

As you can see in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/singleton-database-class), many suggest that I should create an `ICommand` and `IConnection` interface to make it easier to refactor.

In my examples I will only use `IConnection`, but the whole should also be valid for `ICommand`.

I figured I would have to create an interface like this;

```
public interface IConnection
{
     //etc...
}
```

And then, to make the `MySqlConnection` be able to inherit from my `IConnection`, I would have to create my own `MySqlConnection` which would inherit like this;

```
public class MySqlConnection : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, IConnection
{
     //etc...
}
```

Which would mean the new `MySqlConnection` would still have its methods and fields, *and* would inherit from `IConnection`. I should then be able to write a `Database` class like this;

```
public abstract class Database
{
    protected IConnection con;
}
```

And extend it like this;

```
public class MySqlDatabase : Database
{
    private override IConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
}
```

Now, my problem is, `MySqlConnection` is `sealed`; I can't extend it and therefore I do not know any option to make this database class abstract.

The question is; is there a proper way to implement the abstraction of `Database` and if yes, how would I do it?

**Please note** that this question has nothing to do with the class being a singleton (as shown in my CodeReview post). That problem has been issued and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I don't think there is a "the proper way"; there are several ways. My first question would be what the purpose of IConnection is going to be. What does it provide that IDbConnection does not?

Comment: the suggested point is instead of using concreate Connection object specific to a provider, use the Interface IConnection when creating the connection, so, tomorrow if you are changing to another provider you dont have to make any major chganges in your code

Comment: Isn't that what IDbConnection (provided by the framework) is/should be for? And which, I presume, MySqlConnection also implements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the comments on that code review, I actually think they meant use `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` instead of rolling your own. All ADO.NET providers already implement those.

However if you want you could inherit from `DbConnection` and `IConnection` and *wrap* the `MySqlConnection`. You'd have to implement all `DbConnection` methods and relay them to the wrapped connection:

```
public sealed class MyMySqlConnection : DbConnection, IConnection
{
    public MyMySqlConnection(MySqlConnection underlyingConnection)
    {
        UnderlyingConnection = underlyingConnection;
    }

    public MySqlConnection UnderlyingConnection
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override void Open()
    {
        UnderlyingConnection.Open();
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: The most upvoted answer there even mentions IDbConnection in its second bulletpoint. I think that was indeed the intended advice.

Comment: You are totally right. I focussed to much on the guy who told me to use `IConnection` and forgot to check the other answers. My bad I guess. Using `IDbConnection` works as it is supposed to do. Thanks for the workaround you provided anyway, could be of use in the future!

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern:

```
interface IConnection
{
    string ConnectionString {get; set;} // Define your interface explicitly
}
```

Then you can create a class like this:

```
class MySqlDbConnection : IConnection
{
    private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;

    public MySqlConnection(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection)
    {
        // Check for null
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    #region Implementation of IConnection
    public ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return connection.ConnectionString; // Not sure if this is the right name of property
        }
        set
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So what do you achive like this:

1) you can explicitly expose those fields of Connection class that you really need

2) you still can make initial configuration at the stage of initialization of your concrete `Database` class

3) and your code becomes some kind of more abstract

4) and what is very convenient - if connections for different databases (f.e. mysql/sqlite and so on) will have different names of `connectionString` field - then you can wrap them with your single property, defined by your interface. What I mean - you are the one to rule the situation, and inheritance might limit you at this point.

Anyway, before starting to implement something, try to describe everything with interfaces and only then implement classes.